# exception and std::list class

Tags: c++, list, exception, stl

I want to turn the exception handling support off to reduce the code size.

I wonder what happens if an exceptional case is realized in any std::list class operations during run-time.

How is it handled ? What happens ?

Regards.

Comment: Don't do that.  The Standard Library depends on exceptions, and you will ruin your life if you remove them.

Comment: @MooingDuck: exceptions shouldn't happen without extraordinary circumstances in a normal program. I won't touch a code that uses exceptions for normal operations.

Comment: @Dani: I don't touch code that doesn't use exceptions.  When something goes horribly horribly wrong, I don't want to rely on every single programmer remembering to propagate an error code to find out.

Comment: Pretty much the only exceptional case here should be out-of-memory. How often do you see those anyway?

Comment: @MooingDuck: When something goes horribly horribly wrong that is not normal operations. if something goes horribly wrong in an optimized system, the programmer has a freedom of choice to choose either to run fast and crash terribly or to run slower and crash nicely. but the programmer has to have that choice, if a program can't work normally without using exceptions, that program is bad.

Comment: @Dani : The C++ language standard does not give that choice. If you don't want exceptions, don't use a language oriented around them.

Comment: @ildjarn: maybe it doesn't, but g++ and friends do. all they do with exception disable flags is turn `throw` into `exit()` and omit all exception support code.

Comment: It is actually the C++ library standard that doesn't allow for no-exception code. You could substitute a non-standard library (like the one mentioned in my answer :))

Comment: @Dani : But because the OP did not say what compiler/platform they're using, the only unambiguous answer is one that applies to the language itself.

Comment: @Dani: Actually, if they replace exceptions with `exit()`, I'd be OK with that.  I just don't want error codes.

Answer (score 4):

Exception handling is a native part of the C++ language. If you are able to turn of exception support then you have a non-conforming implementation so you need to refer to your specific implementation's documentation to see what restrictions and guarantees it gives in this mode.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at an STL implementation geared to embedded/game programming, like

**[EASTL](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html)**

> Exception handling can be disabled in EASTL by explicitly supported configuration directives.
>
> Almost all game development is done with exception handling disabled. The discussion of this policy is outside the scope of this paragraph, but is handled in [Appendix item 17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html#Appendix_17). It useful if users can explicitly disable exception handling in the libraries that they use, independently of how the compiler is configured for exception handling.

A (portion of) EASTL can be downloaded from github: https://github.com/paulhodge/EASTL